# play alternative video on each page refresh

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

```js
mounted: function() {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube11, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
      disableOn: 700,
      type: 'iframe',
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      removalDelay: 160,
      preloader: false,
      fixedContentPos: false
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumb thumb-caption text-center">
    <figcaption>
      <p>text</p>
      <router-link :to="'/videos'">click here</router-link>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    <a class="popup-youtube11" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8E6xsac2MU">
      <img src="../../.././images/C1M.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="hover-opaque">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle text-center" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the magnific popup plugin to display videos in a popup. The above code plays the same video on page refresh in popup. But, I want to play a different video on page refresh and also change the thumbnails.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: i have attached the same code with this question.the little bit change is i am using multiple div & each div the same jquery is written with different class name thats it.